# I want to send and retrive image form sql server using web service in WPF or Windows Store App in c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an application and I'd like to display the image stored in the DB in an Image through web service. This is my web service current code for sending picture to App:

```
Connection con = new Connection();
con.Start();
DataTable dt = con.Select("Select  ID,Picture ,Customer_Name,Contact_No,Time_In from Customers_Data WHERE   ( Date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,7,GETDATE()),0)  AND  Date < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),1)) And (Sale_Made='No') ");

con.Stop();
List<Customer> ro = new List<Customer>();

foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    string filePath = item["Picture"].ToString();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    byte[] result;
    using (Stream stream = fs)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            // ProfilePicture = result,
        }
    }
    ro.Add(new Customer { Id = item["ID"].ToString(), ProfilePicture = result, Name = item["Customer_Name"].ToString(), Contact = item["Contact_No"].ToString(), Time_In = item["Time_In"].ToString() });
}
return ro;
```

Does anyone know how can I display it? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide what is your problem.

Comment: i just want to send bytes that are store in my databse to the app to show that picture.

Answer (score 0):

Out here, I'm going to a do a small guess because I don't have the full code of your example.

Let's suppose your Web Service method is the following one, you are going to need [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) because you are going to **serialize** the List of Objects.

```
public string GetCustomer()
{
    Connection con = new Connection();
    con.Start();
    DataTable dt = con.Select("Select  ID,Picture ,Customer_Name,Contact_No,Time_In from Customers_Data WHERE   ( Date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,7,GETDATE()),0)  AND  Date < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),1)) And (Sale_Made='No') ");

    con.Stop();
    List<Customer> ro = new List<Customer>();

    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        string filePath = item["Picture"].ToString();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        byte[] result;
        using (Stream stream = fs)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
                // ProfilePicture = result,
            }
        }
        ro.Add(new Customer { Id = item["ID"].ToString(), ProfilePicture = result, Name = item["Customer_Name"].ToString(), Contact = item["Contact_No"].ToString(), Time_In = item["Time_In"].ToString() });
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
}
```

Then, you need to add an Image control in your page (XAML):

```
<Image x:Id="imgData" />
```

After that, you need to **deserialize** the JSON from your URL and Cast it to your Class, you need to copy and paste the same one. Also, you need to transform the bytes into a WriteableBitmap.

```
public async void SetProfilePicture()
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

    string url = string.Format("YOUR URL");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(url);

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(result);

    // Bitmap samples are here in a byte array
    byte[] samples = deserialized[0].ProfilePicture;

    //Here you set the width and height
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(128, 128);

    System.IO.Stream bitmapStream = null;
    bitmapStream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    bitmapStream.Position = 0;

    await bitmapStream.WriteAsync(samples, 0, 4 * 128 * 128);

    bitmapStream.Flush();
    imgData.Source = bitmap;
}
```

Please check it, out here you can read more about it:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8202b92-4c0e-4d1e-a2db-4b3ff057c54f/how-to-set-xaml-image-source-from-byte?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Federico Navarrete: is that method for web service or app ...because i need to send bytes from web service to windows app and then convert those bytes for image.    and thanks for seeing my problem

Comment: I'm just checking your code, you haven't provided any code from the WS only from the DB reading where I suppose the byte array is stored.

Comment: can we talk on skype where i can tell you my whole problem

Comment: Hi @shahzad_Ali, regarding Skype no. I don't share it. However, I did I small update including a Web Service with JSON.NET.